# Easier proof of homeomorphism classes of ordinals

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

I found a very interesting paper by V. Kieftenbeld and B. Löwe, ["A classification of ordinal topologies"](https://eprints.illc.uva.nl/id/eprint/232/1/PP-2006-57.text.pdf) which discusses how to classify ordinals according to homeomorphism when they are given their natural order topology.

The result is based on the [Cantor normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_normal_form) for ordinals.  Suppose the nonzero ordinal $\eta$ is written in the form (CNF)
$$\eta=\omega^{\alpha_0}\cdot k_0+\dots+\omega^{\alpha_n}\cdot k_n $$
with decreasing exponents $\alpha_0>\dots>\alpha_n$ and the $k_i$ positive integers.

If the CNF has more than one term, then $\eta$ is homeomorphic to $\omega^{\alpha_0}\cdot k_0+\omega^{\alpha_n}$ (that is, remove any intermediate terms and replace the last integer with $1$). Otherwise, the CNF has just a single term.  The claim is that theses cases form of complete set of ordinal representatives under homeomorphism.

> **Theorem:** Every nonzero ordinal is homeomorphic to an ordinal of the following form:
>
> - $\omega^\beta\cdot k$ with $k$ a positive integer,
> - $\omega^\beta\cdot k+\omega^\gamma$ with $k$ a positive integer and $\gamma<\beta$.
>
> And no two ordinals in this list are homeomorphic.

The compact ordinals in the list are the successor ordinals, of the form $\omega^\beta\cdot k+1$.

The first part of the paper is very clearly written and shows how to reduce $\alpha$ to a homeomorphic ordinal from the list above.

The second part shows that no two ordinals above are homeomorphic to each other.  I am getting totally lost around Lemma 6 when they introduce their notion of "slope" and "top of slope".  I think the alternative approach below would be a simpler way to go about it.

I would appreciate if someone could validate that this approach works (or give an idea what the "slope" stuff is about).

---

Recall the notion of Cantor-Bendixson derivatives (iterated derived sets).  For a topological space $X$ and $\alpha$ ordinal: $X^{(0)}=X$; $X^{(\alpha+1)}=(X^{(\alpha)})'$ for $\alpha$ successor; $X^{(\alpha)}=\bigcap_{\delta<\alpha}X^{(\delta)}$ for $\alpha$ limit.  The following is not too difficult to prove by induction:

**Lemma:** Given a nonzero ordinal $\eta$, its $\alpha$-th Cantor-Bendixson derivative is the set
$$\eta^{(\alpha)} = \{ \omega^\alpha\cdot\zeta \mid \zeta \text{ positive ordinal with } \omega^\alpha\cdot\zeta<\eta \}.$$

Now showing non-isomorphisms among the ordinals in the list above needs checking various combinations.  Lemma 5 in the paper covers basic cases.

The difficult case for me was when $\eta = \omega^\beta\cdot k+\omega^\gamma$ with $k$ a positive integer and $\gamma<\beta$.  Look at $\eta^{(\alpha)}$, consisting of all positive multiples of $\omega^\alpha$ that are less than $\eta$.  If $\alpha<\gamma$, there is no largest such multiple and $\eta^{(\alpha)}$ is not compact.  If $\alpha=\gamma$, $\omega^\beta\cdot k$ is the largest such multiple and $\eta^{(\alpha)}$ is compact. So $\gamma$ is a topological invariant of the ordinal, namely it's the first level at which the Cantor-Bendixson derivative becomes compact.